# Creating a search form in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, forms

I have been learning Laravel over the last day or so and have managed to successfully create some pages on a WAMP setup that display the results of a database query.  I am trying to add a form on the page that allows me to filter and sort the results.  I have run into a problem where I get a ReflectionException stating "Class App\Http\Controllers\Result does not exist."

I have a Controller

```
 <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Input;

class ResultsController2 extends Controller
{
    /*  
        Display results for search query on cars table.
    */

    public function show_all()
    {
        //This will query the database for our cars
        //$cars = DB::connection('mysql')->select("select * from cars");

        $cars = \DB::select('SELECT * FROM `cars` INNER JOIN makes on cars.make=makes.id INNER JOIN models on cars.model=models.id');
        $makes = \DB::select('SELECT * FROM `makes`');

        return view('results2',['cars'=>$cars,'makes'=>$makes]);
    }

    public function show_all_filtered(Result $result)
    {
        $QueryAppend = "";
        if(Input::post())
        {
            $formMake = Input::post('make');
            $QueryAppend = ' WHERE cars.make=`'.$formMake.'`';//This only filters the results if there has been a form selection
        }
        //This will query the database for our cars
        //$cars = DB::connection('mysql')->select("select * from cars");

        $cars = \DB::select(
            'SELECT * FROM `cars` 
            INNER JOIN makes on cars.make=makes.id 
            INNER JOIN models on cars.model=models.id'
            .$QueryAppend);
        $makes = \DB::select('SELECT * FROM `makes`');

        return view('results2',['cars'=>$cars, 'makes'=>$makes]);
    }   
}
```

My routes looks like this :

```
    Route::get('/', 'ResultsController@show_all');

Route::get('/question3','ResultsController2@show_all');
Route::post('/question3','ResultsController2@show_all_filtered');

Route::get('/question4','ResultsController2@show_all');
```

and my Blade looks like this :

```
    <!== This should be the template for the results for the database query -->


@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Question 2')

@section('content')
    <p>Results</p>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="col100">Make</div><div class="col100">Model</div><div class="col100">Reg</div><div class="col100">Mileage</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    @foreach ($cars as $car)
        <div class="grid">

                <div class="col100">
                {{ $car->make }}        
                </div>
                <div class="col100">
                {{ $car->model }}       
                </div>
                <div class="col100">
                {{ $car->number_plate }}        
                </div>
                <div class="col100">
                {{ $car->mileage }}     
                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    @endforeach
    <div class="clear"></div>
    {{ Form::open( ['action'=> 'ResultsController2@show_all_filtered'] ) }}

        <select name"make">
            @foreach ($makes as $make)
                <option value="{{ $make->make }}">{{ $make->make}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        {{ Form::submit('Update') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="col300">
@endsection
```

when i navigate to /question3 i get a list of results and the search form but when i submit the form, the error happens.  If you have any more questions, I would be happy to answer them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the `Result` class at the top of your controller:

```
use App\Path\To\Result;
```

where the `App\Path\To\` portion is the full namespace of the `Result` class.

The problem is this function:

```
public function show_all_filtered(Result $result)
```

PHP assumes the current namespace for the class `Result` since it is not explicitly imported via `use`.

Comment: I completely missed that. It looks like i included request instead of response!

Comment: oh actually its worse than that. I never meant to include result.  I should of added request to the function input variables instead of result

Comment: Just FYI, if `Request $request` is the only parameter in a controller function, you can omit it and use either the `request()` helper method or the `Request::` facade. Both are equivalent.